# Document Management System File name problem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document, office

So I have a file I have been versioning in SP that is called myFile.ppt on our Enterprise SharePoint. Our team recently transitioned version of Power Point so now the default is myFile.pptx. Problem is that SP does not see this as a new version of the myFile.ppt since there is a name change (the "x" at the end of the extension). I know I can save the pptx back to ppt but I prefer the pptx as it is more flexible. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. with your old .ppt available, open windows explorer
2. rename the file `myFile.ppt` to `myFile.pptx`
3. refresh your view/page
4. upload and overwrite `myFile.pptx` (the new version)
5. if your file was v2.0, now it will be v3.0

please keep in mind that I am not suggesting you do this.

in fact, you are specifying that this document is in 2010+ format, which it is not (in it's previous versions), so accessing the previous versions may reveal to be problematic

IMO you should leave the old one alone, archive it, delete it, etc., and upload the new one as a brand new document. but, this is possible using the above method

Comment: Thanks Tiago. I went with your suggestion of simply uploading the new ones as a brand new document.